# How to make python function start back over if conditions aren't met?

Tags: python, arrays, function, loops

I am trying to create a function that spreads a rumor form one pixel in to other neighboring pixels as long as they == 1 (not a 0). I think the function I have now can spread it to the neighboring pixel one time, but I want it to loop again and again using the updated versions of the pixel map each time. How can I get it to loop back to the top when certain conditions aren't met?

```
def spread_rumor(array):
    
    new_array = np.zeros_like(array)                                #make a copy of your city

    for i in range(array.shape[0]):                                 #for each index i for the number of rows:
        for j in range(array.shape[1]):                             #for each index j for the number of columns
            if array[i,j] == 0:
                new_array[i,j] = 0
            elif array[i,j] == 2:
                new_array[i,j] = 2
            elif array[i,j] == 1:                                   #if the value of the city/board at [i,j] is a 1:
                new_array[i,j] = 1                                  #we only do something if we find a person who can learn the rumor
                neighbors = getNeighborValues(i,j, array)           #get all of the values of their neighborhood cells
                if np.any(np.array(neighbors) == 2) == True:
                    new_array[i,j] = 2                       
                                                                    
            ## there is more than one way to do this!
            ## You could use a loop to check all the neighbors and move one once you find one
            ## or you could check to see if there is a 2 in any of the neighbors


            

    frac_empty = np.count_nonzero(array == 0)/array.size

    frac_house = np.count_nonzero(array == 1)/array.size
    
    frac_rumor = np.count_nonzero(array == 2)/array.size
    

    if frac_empty + frac_rumor == 1.0:                                           #the copy of our city is the same as city: 
        ##our simulation isn't changing anymore,
        ##so making a copy and updating it isn't going to
        ##lead to further changes
        spread_rumor = False   
    else:
        ##there are still changes going on
        #this is where I would want it to start back over at the top again

    return showCity(new_array)                 #this function creates a plt.imshow representation of the resulting array
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few loops you could apply to achieve something like this. Firstly, a `while` loop. `while` loops, as you may know, run until a condition is met. If you have many conditions, the `while` statement can get pretty ugly. Many choose to use `while True` if there are many conditions. Using `break` will exit the loop.

```
def rand_string():
    while True:
        string = "".join(random.sample("abcdefghijk", 7))
        if string == "afedgcb":
            break
        elif string == "cdefgab":
            break
        elif string == "gbadcef":
            break
        else:
            continue

    return string
```

Above, we choose 7 random letters from the string `abcdefghijk` and check if the 7 random letters make either `afedgcb`, `cdefgab`, or `gbadcef`. If so, we break out of the loop and return the string. If not, we will restart the loop. The `else/continue` is not necessary, the loop will still start over if none of the conditions are met because we don't break out of the loop.

Another option is recursion. The example below simply chooses a random number from 0 and 10 and checks if it equals 5. If so, we return the number. If not, we just run the function again.

```
def rand_num_recursion():
    num = random.randint(0,10)
    if num == 5:
        return num
    else:
        return rec()
```

Now, if you were to `print(rec())`, the answer would always be 5. Why? Because the function will continue to run until the random number chosen is 5. This recursive function can also easily be converted to a `while` loop:

```
def rand_num_while():
    num = random.randint(0,10)
    while num != 5:
        num = random.randint(0,10)
    return num
```

#### What if you have parameters?

With recursion this can be done easily. Of course, the below example is just for demonstration purposes - you would never really need a function to "empty" a list, it is just an example of how to pass updated parameters back to the beginning of the loop.

```
def empty_list(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return lst
    else:
        print(lst)
        return empty_list(lst[:-1]) # return all members of the list except for the last one
```

When you write `print(empty_list([1,2,3,4,5,6]))` and keep the `print(lst)` in the function, the output is as follows:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2]
[1]
[]
```

As you can see, every time the condition is not met, we pass an updated parameter back to the beginning of the loop. In this example, you can see that every time the loop occurs, it removes the last element from the list and passes it back to the beginning.